# Get post id during `delete_post` action in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have this code

```
add_action( 'delete_post', 'my_delete_function' );
 function my_delete_function() { 
   global $wpdb;
   $wpdb->query("
    DELETE FROM wp_votes WHERE post=".$thePostID."
;);
 }
```

How can I get the id of the post being deleted?

Additionally, will this still work if multiple posts are deleted in the admin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hooks automatically pass the deleted post id into your function, so you can just catch that, check the docs [here](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/delete_post):

```
add_action( 'delete_post', 'my_delete_function' );
function my_delete_function($postId) { 
   global $wpdb;
   $wpdb->query("
       DELETE FROM wp_votes WHERE post=".$postId."
   ;);
}
```